# Create a list from a dictionary cycle

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I would like to create a list with this dict

```json
{
    "v3bf33-srv01": "eu-west0-a",
    "v3bf33-srv02": "eu-west0-a",
    "v3bf33-srv03": "eu-west0-a",
    "v3bf33-srv04": "eu-west0-b",
    "v3bf33-srv05": "eu-west0-b",
    "v3bf33-srv06": "eu-west0-b",
    "v3bf33-srv07": "eu-west0-c",
    "v3bf33-srv08": "eu-west0-c",
    "v3bf33-srv09": "eu-west0-c",
}
```

if a user ask 5 servers ( in a pipeline), cycle through servers of each value: `eu-west0-a`, `eu-west0-b`, `eu-west0-c`, then, `eu-west0-a`, `eu-west0-b`.

The result should be a list containing only the server name.

E.g.:

```yaml
- v3bf33-srv01    #eu-west0-a
- v3bf33-srv04    #eu-west0-b
- v3bf33-srv07    #eu-west0-c
- v3bf33-srv02    #eu-west0-a
- v3bf33-srv05    #eu-west0-b
```

any help is welcome. ^^

Comment: please  if someone have an idea

Comment: @Vladimir Botka  why did you delete?

Comment: i see a lot of post from you .. and comments say ' its work" ... and your exemple is ko on my side.. i am upset of me.

Comment: @Vladimir Botka i ask a friend to test your exemple.. same resultat as me...
nned a spécific version of ansible ? my ansible 2.9.6 and    jinja10.